# AnimateSharedLayout and LayoutGroup in framer Motion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I recently started to use the `framer-motion` library within a `react, typescript` project to handle the animations. when I tried to use `<AnimateSharedLayout>` with `type` prop, it shows there's no such property with `AnimateSharedLayout`. I'm a bit confused here because in their documentation and all the other articles I've found say we can use the `type="crossfade"` prop on the `AnimateSharedLayout` to smooth the animations. I'm using framer-motion: 5.3.3, and I saw in their upgrade manual, they are removing `AnimateSharedLayout` and instead introducing `LayoutGroup`. [here's the doc](https://www.framer.com/docs/guide-upgrade/)
But in `LayoutGroup` also haven't had any such prop called 'type' to use the `crossfade`.
Any suggestions would be great, since I have no idea what the doc suggesting and how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Crossfade is applied automatically. Source: https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/#shared-layout-animations

> If the old component is still mounted when the new component enters, they will automatically crossfade from the old to the new.

Layout animations can be customised via the `transition` property as well: https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/##customising-layout-animations